# create a button which creates another button just below when clicked in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to create a button on my webpage in jsp. When i click this button,a new button should appear on the same page,without changing anything else on the page.

i want the new button to appear just below or on next line of the button clicked

```
  <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="bulk_submission" value="Start a new submission"
    onclick="myFunction();"/>       
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
     <input class="btn btn-succes" type="button" name="new_file" value="new file"
    onclick="myFunction2();"/>      
    }
    </script>   
<script>
     function myFunction2()
    { alert("file uploaded");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write like this

```js
  < input class = "btn btn-success"
  type = "button"
  name = "bulk_submission"
  value = "Start a new submission"
  onclick = "myFunction();" / >
    < script >
    function myFunction() {

      var anotherBtn = "<input class=\"btn btn-succes\" type=\"button\" name=\"new_file\" value=\"new file\" onclick=\"myFunction2();\"/>"
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = anotherBtn;
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

  function myFunction2() {
    alert("file uploaded");
  } < /script>
```

Comment: what if i want to run a python code from my system in background when i click the second button

Comment: you can bind ajax function to send a request to you python code

Comment: can u give me an example

Comment: you can google ajax + python there has lot of examples ☺

Comment: Im getting the button in end of the page. I want the new button to just appear below the new button. What modification should i do?